# How array reallocates memory during run time in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic-memory-allocation

since Array is structure(value type), its allocates in stack memory which is during compile time.
But we can increase size of array, append elements during runtime even thou memory allocated in stack is fixed.
How it is possible, how it works, where it takes memory to expand?

is memory required at all to store references to objects if array holds references as value type?

What if arrays elements also a value type?

Comment: The source code for it is publicly available, as you can see (https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L310) the elements are not stored as part of the `Array` object itself, it stores a reference to a buffer where the array elements are stored

Comment: Arrays in Swift aren't like arrays in other languages where they are always static. Array is like `List` in Java or `Vec` in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Array does not hold objects at all. It holds a Buffer, which contains a Storage. The specific types used for the buffer and storage depend on various things, including the size of the array and whether it needs to bridge to ObjC. One example pairing is a [_ContiguousArrayBuffer](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/531dd3aa1fa4ca2ce8f889fcbf4baade5b7d730a/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift#L280) and a [_ContiguousArrayStorage](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/531dd3aa1fa4ca2ce8f889fcbf4baade5b7d730a/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift#L76).

Storage are reference types and are heap-allocated.

Arrays present value *semantics*. That does not mean that their storage is entirely on the stack. Internally they can have reference types (and even share buffers with other Array values, which they do often), as long as they present an interface that is equivalent to each Array being independent. This is the basis of the [copy-on-write optimization](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#advice-use-copy-on-write-semantics-for-large-values).

Comment: in other words array holds reference to buffer in heap, and behaves like value type?

Comment: what if elements are structs? does that mean array will be on stack entirely?

Comment: Correct. I believe there are cases where the data is small enough that everything is inlined to the stack anyway, but I haven't actually seen code that supports that. (I *think* the compiler can do this for certain small arrays, but don't hold me to that. As a best assumption, assume the data itself is stored on the heap)

Comment: Structs vs classes has no impact here. If it did, you'd expect an array of a few thousand structs to overflow the stack, and it doesn't.

Comment: "Every array reserves a specific amount of memory to hold its contents. When you add elements to an array and that array begins to exceed its reserved capacity, the array allocates a larger region of memory and copies its elements into the new storage." does reference to storage change when this happens, if YES, how does my variable knows that reference to storage changed and it needs to track new storage?

Comment: That is correct. But all of that happens on the heap.

Comment: It doesn't "track new storage." The storage is still the same instance of _ContiguousArrayStorage. Inside of `_ContiguousArrayStorage`, a malloc'ed buffer has been reallocated. For an example of how it does that, see https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8aaf18093f43845e73a58bd3ed88cc17bd26078/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift#L1066-L1087  (Swift Arrays are nothing like C arrays. `xs[4]` absolutely does not take the address of `xs` and add 4 like in C. It is nothing like that. It calls a `subscript` method and does whatever lookups it needs.)

Comment: (There are ways that the compiler can optimize this down to "some pointer + 4" due to all the inlining that's done. But that does not mean it's how it logically works.)